# Update splitViewController from ModalViewController

Tags: ipad, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I need to update on of my splitView's from a modalView, but I am not having any luck.

for instance: From my rootView (which is a UITableVIewController) if I set an option to hide a certain section from the rootView table in my ModalView, when I dismiss the modalview, the setting doesnt take affect on screen for the tableview, same goes for detailView.

i've tried:

```
    MyRootView *mrv = [MyRootView alloc] init];
    [mrv updateTable];
    [mrv release];
```

[mrv updateTable]; is located in my RootView and contains a [tableView reloadData];
If I place an NSLog in there, that prints, just that the table doesnt reload while on screen.

Even tried viewWill/DidAppear, no avail.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to resolve this issue with Notifications.

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"update" object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateView:) name:@"update" object:nil];
    - (void)updateView:(NSNotification *)notification {
        [tableView reloadData];
    }
```